# can I use object operator -> in if statement

Tags: php

Hi I have `$images[ ]` as an array containing selected rows from my database and I want to echo a link if the link field in the row is not null.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($images[1]->link)){
    echo"<p>".$images[1]->link."</p>";
} ?>
```

I'm just starting out so I appreciate any help.

Comment: try  ...  is not difficult  ..  you have errror?

Comment: Your code is totally valid. Run it and check how it works.

Comment: many thanks, it works. Sorry, I made a mistake, I had a session running so that when I refreshed the page the error message was still showing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES! If `$images[1]` contains an Object which has a link property and if that property is something that evaluates to true, the block will be executed.

```
class Test {
  public $link = true;
}

$images = [new Test(), new Test()];

if ($images[1]->link) { /* will run */ }
```

If the `$link` property can be null, you also write:

```
if (!is_null($images[1]->link)) { … }
```